# Changing the value of an attribute of the document element in an xml file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to change the value of an attribute of the document element in an XML file using XSLT transformation. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:xmlgMsc xmlns:ns1="org.example" formatVersion="1.0" name="BlaBlah" pathName="/system/abc.xml" writtenBy="Me me me">
   <ns1:blockRoot someAtt="0" anotherAtt="1" />
</ns1:xmlgMsc>
```

Here I would like to change the "pathName" to some another path (say "/local/xyz.xml"). Can somebody please provide the syntax or point me into the right direction for doing this in XSLT?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a stylesheet that consists of two templates. The identity template (look it up) and this one:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/@pathName">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="'/local/xyz.xml'" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You could use an `<xsl:param>` to pass in the new path dynamically, if you don't want to hard-code the new value.

Minor correction: The *root node* (`/`) of an XML document does not have attributes. You mean the *document element* (`/ns1:xmlgMsc`), that's one level down the hierarchy.

Comment: I am afraid it didn't work me ... any idea if I am doing anything wrong? This is a small xslt I made;

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/@pathName">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select="'/local/xyz.xml'" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>